# How do I wrap ruby IO with a sliding window filter

Tags: ruby, io

I'm using an opaque API in some ruby code which takes a File/IO as a parameter.  I want to be able to pass it an IO object that only gives access to a given range of data in the real IO object.

For example, I have a 8GB file, and I want to give the api an IO object that has a 1GB range within the middle of my real file.

```
real_file = File.new('my-big-file')
offset = 1 * 2**30 # start 1 GB into it
length = 1 * 2**30 # end 1 GB after start
filter = IOFilter.new(real_file, offset, length)

# The api only sees the 1GB of data in the middle
opaque_api(filter)
```

The [filter_io](https://github.com/jasoncodes/filter_io) project looks like it would be the easiest to adapt to do this, but doesn't seem to support this use case directly.

Answer (score 1):

I think you would have to write it yourself, as it seems like a rather specific thing: you would have to implement all (or, a subset that you need) of `IO`'s methods using a chunk of the opened file as a data source. An example of the "speciality" would be writing to such stream - you would have to take care not to cross the boundary of the segment given, i.e. constantly keeping track of your current position in the big file. Doesn't seem like a trivial job, and I don't see any shortcuts that could help you there.

Perhaps you can find some OS-based solution, e.g. making a loopback device out of the part of the large file (see [`man losetup`](http://fclose.com/p/linux/man/8-losetup/) and particularly `-o` and `--sizelimit` options, for example).

Variant 2:

If you are ok with keeping the contents of the window in memory all the time, you may wrap [`StringIO`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/stringio/rdoc/classes/StringIO.html) like this (just a sketch, not tested):

```
def sliding_io filename, offset, length
  File.open(filename, 'r+') do |f|
    # read the window into a buffer
    f.seek(offset)
    buf = f.read(length)
    # wrap a buffer into StringIO and pass it given block
    StringIO.open(buf) do |buf_io|
      yield(buf_io)
    end
    # write altered buffer back to the big file
    f.seek(offset)
    f.write(buf[0,length])
  end
end
```

And use it as you would use block variant of `IO#open`.

Comment: Would prefer not to keep it in memory, it could be GBs at a time.  Right now I'm shelling out to 'slice' the file to a tempdir, buts its pretty slow (multiGB), and only adequate for prototyping.  In this case I don't ever need to write to the file, just read from it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the IO object has the functionality you are looking for.  I've used it before for MD5 hash summing similarly sized files.

```
incr_digest = Digest::MD5.new()
file = File.open(filename, 'rb') do |io|
    while chunk = io.read(50000)
        incr_digest << chunk
    end
end
```

This was the block I used, where I was passing the chunk to the MD5 Digest object.

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/IO.html#M000918

Comment: I believe all you are doing here is passing a string (read returns a string/data to be assigned to chunk, not an instance of the IO class) through to incr_digest, unless I'm missing something...?

Comment: Nope, you are correct, that is exactly what it does.  My bad.  However, it seems like you could use this as an optimized tool for chunk-ing your data, then sending it to your API as a IO object... 

I'm looking at the StringIO having that functionality.  http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/stringio/rdoc/index.html